# BigQuery Standard Get first not null value when grouping

Tags: google-bigquery, coalesce

I have a table like this:

```
CUSTOMERS_ID  DATE_SALES  DIMENSION
MARIO1        20200201    NULL
MARIO1        20200113    Spain
MARIO2        20200131    NULL
MARIO3        20200101    France
MARIO3        20191231    Spain
```

and I need to order by *CUSTOMERS_ID* and *DATE_SALES* DESC fields. Then I want to group by *CUSTOMERS_ID* field and get first not null value of *DIMENSION* field. 
The output table would be:

```
CUSTOMERS_ID  DIMENSION
MARIO1        Spain
MARIO2        NULL
MARIO3        France
```

Any ideas? I have tried `COALESCE` functions, `FIRST_VALUE`, and I have not the results I had expected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY IF(DIMENSION IS NULL, NULL, DATE_SALES) DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS_ID
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row CUSTOMERS_ID    DATE_SALES  DIMENSION    
1   MARIO1          20200113    Spain    
2   MARIO2          20200131    null     
3   MARIO3          20200101    France
```

Comment: ARRAY_AGG and OFFSET are my new best friends. Thanks Mikhail!

Answer (score 9):

You can group by customer id and use ARRAY_AGG by ignoring NULLS, and you can also order by date in that field.
Limit 1 will make it more efficient by using less RAM storage.
And then, OFFSET(0) will make it an unnested field, so you can use that field easily.

```
WITH 
raw_data AS
(
  SELECT 'MARIO1' CUSTOMERS_ID, 20200201 DATE_SALES, NULL as DIMENSION UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MARIO1' CUSTOMERS_ID, 20200113 DATE_SALES, 'Spain' as DIMENSION UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MARIO2' CUSTOMERS_ID, 20200131 DATE_SALES, NULL as DIMENSION UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MARIO3' CUSTOMERS_ID, 20200101 DATE_SALES, 'France' as DIMENSION UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MARIO3' CUSTOMERS_ID, 20191231 DATE_SALES, 'Spain' as DIMENSION
)
SELECT CUSTOMERS_ID, ARRAY_AGG(DIMENSION IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY DATE_SALES DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] as DIMENSION
FROM raw_data
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just use a `ROW_NUMBER` trick here:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT CUSTOMERS_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMERS_ID
                          ORDER BY -1.0*UNIX_SECONDS(DATE_SALES) DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT CUSTOMERS_ID, DIMENSION
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY CUSTOMERS_ID;
```

The logic is to order row number *descending* by the negative number of seconds since the epoch.  This places more recent sales first, and also places `NULL` at the very end, so a `NULL` value would only receive row number 1 in the event that no non `NULL` dimension data be available.